# Problems Receiving QSerialPort Signals

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-signals, qtserialport

I'm trying to write a simple program to test out the serial port, but am having trouble getting QSerialPort to work. I never receive signals from the QSerialPort object. I get 3 runtime warnings/errors that I think probably have something to do with it.

The errors are:

```
QApplication::qAppName: Please instantiate the Qapplication object first
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

The code snippet below is the smallest sample I can give to recreate the errors, it doesn't show me connecting signals but I think these errors are why I don't see them. If I don't call the open function none of the errors occur.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QSerialPort>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    PowerBoardGUI w;
    w.show();

    QSerialPort* serial = new QSerialPort();


    serial->setPortName("/dev/ttyS1");
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);

    bool isOpen = serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    serial->close();
    delete serial;


    return a.exec();
}
```

The test system is Redhat 5.6. A static version of QT 4.7.4. And the latest version of QSerialPort (built from GIT today).

Comment: We do not support Qt 4.7 in QtSerialPort, so you better get a newer Qt version for starter. Secondly, `serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);` is pointless because that is the default. Thirdly, you have not checked against errors after open. Fourthly, close is unnecessary since it is called in the dtor thanks to C++ RAII. Fifthly, you should not use raw pointers, actually here, you could even use a stack object. Sixthly, this code would not even compile as it does not include the PowerBoardGUI header.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I did not realize Qt4.7 was unsupported. Unfortunately I'm stuck using it, so I will have to explore alternative options. By check for errors do you just mean making sure that isOpen is true? Moving the QtSerialPort to the stack still results in the same errors. And you're right, that was a copy and paste error, but other then not compiling should not affect the issue.

Comment: after open, you could print out serial.errorString() if the return value is false. Is the open successful? If not, what is the error string?